# Django field.choices + HTML. How do I get the word display, not id?

Tags: django

I have a this list in .models

```
SIDES = (
        [1, 'Attack'],
        [2, 'Defense'],
    )
    side = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( ("side"), choices=SIDES)
```

and here i trying display on page 'Attack' or 'Defense', but he display only '1' or '2'

```
{% for el in operators %}
       <div>
           <h3>{{ el.side }}</h3>
       </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

How do I get the word display, not id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the docs :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/

```
{% for el in operators %}
   <div>
       <h3>{{ el.get_side_display }}</h3>
   </div>
```

{% endfor %}